# Making a compiled Autohotkey script "generic"

Tags: compilation, autohotkey, generic-programming

When implementing “Image Search” within Autohotkey, the screen shot tucked away in folder in ..\MacroCreator\Screenshots.. under C:\Users\Rasstag...

If the intent is to develop a generic compiled script which can be used on PCs other than the developer, the path to 'screenshots' must not be an absolute path.

What would be the recommended approach to make a compiled script truly “generic”?

Any insight would be appreciated...

Comment: What have you tried?  What issues did you have?  Did you look at the AHK documentation?  Anyway, in AHK you have access to environmental variables, so `EnvGet, Loc, USERPROFILE` will also get you `C:\Users\Rasstag` on your profile.  You can build the full path from there.  But, you can also use the `FSO` and/or any `user input` to have the generic target location established in your generic program.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment,

```
 EnvGet, Loc, USERNAME
 Loc := Loc . "\MacroCreator\Screenshots"
```

Hth,

Comment: Or: `Loc := A_UserName . "\MacroCreator\Screenshots"` (without the first line).

Comment: Thanks PGilm... I'm just starting down this road... discovered Autohotkey yesterday.. ;)

I'll experiment with these variables and see if I can figure out how to get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

Look for "Built-in Variables" in the help files. They provide a lot of useful information. Find the group of variables listed under "Operating System and User Info."

Eg.

Name := A_UserName
MsgBox %Name%